# Alternative for SearchPreferencePage class

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

The class `org.eclipse.search.internal.ui.searchpreferencepage.java` is not available on eclipse 3.7.2. Is there any alternatives for this class?

Comment: It is an internal class.What you want to do with this class?

Comment: We are using this class for printing search results